# How to export all Latitude - Longitude values of each pixel included in the area covered by geometry at specific resolution? - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, latitude-longitude

I am able to add a band of lat - lon in my image in google EE with the code:

```
var imgwithlonlat = meanImage.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat());
```

Now I want to store all these values in a list and export it to drive in some format. How can I do that? I also want to store the pixel values along with Lon-Lat. Is there any way to do that in Google EE?